# Ubuntu 12.04 gnome-terminal gets crash

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

My ubuntu gnome-terminal gets crash

when I try to click on the terminal icon it opens and flicks continues and it gets scroll down automatically.

I try to reinstall the gnome-terminal by using software center and gets the same problem..

Here is the screen shot for reference..[image: gnome-terminal]

Comment: try asking question on askubuntu.com

Comment: Hi Tejas, Yes I did that, Thanks for your help.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create some user, reboot the system and login into different user and let us know if you see the same problem.

Comment: Hi Max, Wow.. works fine, but what will be the cause for that particular user...??